# How to get the instance when upload file using model FileField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-forms

I am new to Django...I have a model FileField to upload document, and I want the file path is according to the client ID.

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1av2.png)

I have a Customer model and I have a upload model, linked to Customer:

model.py

```
class BasicUploadTo():
    prefix = ''
    suffix = dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

    def upload_rules(self, instance, filename):
        (filename, extension) = os.path.splitext(filename)
        id = instance.customer_id.customer_id.user_id
        return os.path.join(str(id), "Docs", f"{self.prefix}_{self.suffix}{extension}")

    def upload_br(self, instance, filename):
        instance1 = Customer.customer_id
        self.prefix = "BR"
        dir = self.upload_rules(instance, filename)
        return dir

class AttachmentsBasic(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.OneToOneField("Customer", verbose_name="client ID", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=True)
    br = models.FileField(upload_to=BasicUploadTo().upload_br, verbose_name="BR", null=True, blank=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.OneToOneField("UserID", blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="Client ID", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    ...

class UserID(models.Model):

    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, verbose_name="Client ID")

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "Client"
        verbose_name_plural = "Client"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user_id}"
```

form.py:

```
class ClientUploadForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = AttachmentsBasic
    fields = ( "br",)

def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ClientUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(path)
    for x in self.fields:
        self.fields[x].required = False

def save(self, client_id, commit=True):
    
    clientDoc = super(ClientUploadForm, self).save(commit=True)
    print(self)

    instance = Customer.objects.get(customer_id__user_id=client_id)
    clientDoc.customer_id = instance

    if commit:
        clientDoc.save()
    return clientDoc
```

views.py

```
def clienInfo(request, client):
clientsIDs = [c.customer_id.user_id for c in Customer.objects.all()]

if client in clientsIDs:
    matching_client = Customer.objects.filter(customer_id__user_id=client)

    if request.method == "POST":
        instance = Customer.objects.get(customer_id__user_id=client)
        uploadForm = ClientUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance.customer_id.user_id)
        if uploadForm.is_valid():
            uploadForm.save(request.POST["customer_id"])
        else:
            print("Client's document form got error.")
    else:
        print("Client form got error.")
    uploadForm = ClientUploadForm
    sale = sales.objects.all()
    return render(request=request,
                template_name="home/client-info-test.html",
                context={"clientInfo": matching_client,
                        "uploadForm": uploadForm,
                        "sales": sale})
```

But I got none when I upload file though my site, but I can upload the file though Django admin page

```
<input type="file" class="" name="br">
```

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTf0M.png)

Could someone help me...many thanks!!!!!

Comment: you also post the code of your <form> .... </form> in the template, it is likely where the problem is coming from

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have add                 "<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">" in my code, but it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, just use the {{form.br}} in the frontend site, use the original form from the view.
view.py

```
def updateClienInfo(request, client_id):

    clientDoc = AttachmentsBasic.objects.get(customer_id__customer_id__user_id=client_id)
    docForm = ClientUploadForm(instance=clientDoc)

    if request.method == "POST":
     docForm = ClientUploadForm(request.POST or None,
                           request.FILES or None,
                           instance=clientDoc)
        if docForm.is_valid():
            docForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            print(docForm.errors)
            print("Upload document form got errors.")
    else:
        print("Client's saving form got error.")

    return render(request=request,
            template_name="home/client-info-test1.html",
            context={"docForm" : docForm,
                    })
```

home/client-info-test1.html

```
<div class="card-body">
  <label class="card-text">BR</label>
    {{docForm.br}}
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class ClientUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ("company_name", ...) #your model field name
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

        for x in self.fields:
            self.fields[x].required = False
```